# Variable Pyomo bounds

Tags: pyomo

I'm modelling a 100 kWh battery. I have a set containing 24 hours.
Is it possible to have different upper bounds for charging the battery based on the battery's state of charge(SOC) which i don't know yet?
The SOC is decided later by the solver.

eg. at 50 % SOC the charging has an upper bound of 30 kW.
at 20  % SOC the charging has an upper bound of 10 kW.
The upper bound for charging is different for each SOC

```
def battery_upper_bound(m,t):              
        return m.bat_charing[t] <= max(pyo.value(m.SOC[t]*4.18)),5) 
m.battery_Max_charge_c = pyo.Constraint(m.t, rule=battery_upper_bound)
```

My approach with pyo.value(m.SOC[t]) uses the initialized SOC value and is therefore equal in all timesteps and obviously not a feasible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If the relationship between these two variables is linear (or if that is a good enough approximation) as you have coded, then this is easy.  All you need to do is get rid of the `max()` function because max is a non-linear operation.  This can be done by just breaking your constraint into two constraints

```
def battery_charge_lim(m, t):              
  return m.bat_charging[t] <= m.SOC[t]*4.18 
m.batt_charge_lim = pyo.Constraint(m.t, rule=battery_charge_lim)

def battery_max_rate(m, t):
  return m.bat_charging[t] <= 5
m.battery_max_charge = pyo.Constraint(m.t, rule=battery_max_rate)
```